# (Closed) Maven is not work in Java 11 should I downgrade?

Tags: java, maven

I have been trying to solve this issue for 3 hours and I don't know what the problem is.

For reference I am running Java 11 and I am using java parbolied 1.18. This the error that I have waisted so much time on:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating extended parser class: null
at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:58)
at com.mycompany.myname.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.parboiled.transform.AsmUtils.createClassReader(AsmUtils.java:56)
at org.parboiled.transform.ClassNodeInitializer.process(ClassNodeInitializer.java:62)
at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:44)
at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.transformParser(ParserTransformer.java:39)
at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:54)
... 1 more
```

> This is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>MyName</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.parboiled/parboiled-java -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.parboiled</groupId>
       <artifactId>parboiled-java</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the 15th line of your Main.java??

Comment: It looks like a bug in your code, not Maven.  I see no reason why downgrading to an obsolete / end-of-life version of Java would help.  You probably just need to debug your code + the parboiled library to figure out what has gone wrong.

Comment: TimeParser parser = Parboiled.createParser(TimeParser.class); This is the 15th line of my main

Comment: I tried debugging my code: I get the same message. Just like the one below this

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.parboiled.transform.AsmUtils.createClassReader(AsmUtils.java:56)
 at org.parboiled.transform.ClassNodeInitializer.process(ClassNodeInitializer.java:62)
 at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:44)

Comment: You are writing about Java 8 in your title but Maven is configured to compile Java 11! There is some sort of mismatch.

Comment: Your are right I am running Java 11

Comment: Its not an issue related to maven, please change the title of this post. Its related to code that you wrote. Please recheck the code or post it here.

Comment: https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/tree/master/examples-java/src/main/java/org/parboiled/examples/time

Comment: These are the two codes that giving me the error

Comment: Try the latest version of parboiled-java https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.parboiled/parboiled-java/1.3.1

Answer (score 3):

The problem is located in the used library cause the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating extended parser class: null
at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:58)
at com.mycompany.myname.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.parboiled.transform.AsmUtils.createClassReader(AsmUtils.java:56)
at org.parboiled.transform.ClassNodeInitializer.process(ClassNodeInitializer.java:62)
at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:44)
at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.transformParser(ParserTransformer.java:39)
at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:54)
```

exactly shows that it is using asm access to class files which is JDK dependent which needs to be upgraded/updated in the code to work correctly with JDK 11. The [referenced library](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled) is not working with JDK 11. Already has several issues related to JDK11.

This has nothing to do with Maven. Maven works up to most recent versions of JDK 15...16(EA)...etc.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help. The issue was that I needed to update to the latest java paraboiled.